# Is there an index that would support comparison of 2-tuple values?

Tags: postgresql, index

I want to implement [cursor-based pagination](https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-implement-cursor-pagination-like-a-pro-513140b65f32) for a large data set.

With `OFFSET` based pagination, when the user wants page `N`, you just `OFFSET` `N * page_size`.
The query ends up like:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM books
ORDER BY id
OFFSET 100000
LIMIT 10;
```

But `OFFSET` gets slower the larger the value it's given because PostgreSQL has to load and discard the preceding rows.

A cursor-based approach is where we tell the user "here's page `N`, and since the last record on it has `id` of `X`, to get the next page you should ask me for records with `id > X`."
The query ends up like:

```
SELECT *
FROM books
WHERE id > 100000
ORDER BY id
LIMIT 10;
```

In that case, PostgreSQL can load only the needed rows.

That works great when sorting by `id`.
But I'd like to be able to sort by other columns - for instance, by `title` - and still paginate.

The problem is that `title` is not unique. So if the final record on page `N` has the title "About Weasels" and there are multiple books with that title, requesting the next page with `WHERE title > 'About Weasels'` may skip some of them.

I can get unique values by having the user request `WHERE (title, id) > ('About Weasels', 100000)`, but that performs poorly because PostgreSQL has to compute `(title, id)` for every row.

I tried adding an index to pre-compute that 2-tuple: `CREATE INDEX books_title_and_id ON books (title, id);`

...but that index makes no difference to the query plan.

Is there an index I could create which would speed up this query?

Comment: If I use concatenation I can get it to work. So `CREATE INDEX books_title_and_id ON books ((title || ' ' || id));` and `SELECT *
FROM books
WHERE ((title || ' ' || id)) > (('About Weasels' || ' ' || 100000000))
ORDER BY ((title || ' ' || id))
LIMIT 1;
` is fast. But it's ugly IMO.

Comment: The index you described works fine or me.  What version of PostgreSQL are you using?

Comment: See my long answer to https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/295996/quering-millions-of-rows-is-still-slow-with-index-and-a-materialized-view?noredirect=1#comment578589_295996

Comment: This is actually know as [Keyset Pagination](https://use-the-index-luke.com/no-offset), and yeah, the ordering needs to be unique, so `order by title, id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example using your index:

```
explain analyze 
select * from books WHERE 
(title, id) > ('KVFNdl5F', 994364) 
order by title, id 
limit 10;
```

Note that the first occurrence of `title, id` (in the > comparison) must be in parentheses, and the second occurrence (in the ORDER BY) must *not* be in parentheses.

```
                                                                QUERY PLAN                                                                 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.42..1.09 rows=10 width=45) (actual time=0.062..0.081 rows=10 loops=1)
   ->  Index Scan using books_title_and_id on books  (cost=0.42..42823.96 rows=644090 width=45) (actual time=0.060..0.077 rows=10 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (ROW(title, id) > ROW('KVFNdl5F'::text, 994364))
 Planning Time: 0.107 ms
 Execution Time: 0.109 ms
```

Comment: Awesome! I'm confused about why the index isn't used for `ORDER BY (title, id)`, though - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-ordering.html seems to say that it would be, especially when used with a `LIMIT`.